# Why openERP response is in [u'india] format

Tags: python, odoo

I have a basic requirement where I need to generate states based on country selected in ERP employee module. It was fine in fetching the states according the country. But the response I get is in format `[u'alaska']`. I only need `alaska`.

Here is my implementation:

```
cr.execute("select name from res_country where id=%d" %swap_addresses)
countryName =  str(map(lambda x:x[0], cr.fetchall()))                
return {'value':{'states': str(countryName)}}
```

Comment: That is a list with one Unicode string in. I think you want `countryName = map(lambda x:x[0], cr.fetchall())[0]` (note that you can use `operator.itemgetter(0)` instead of the `lambda`).